# EF Help, NotSupportedException: property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Thanks for reading, I am using EntityFramework and received this error message

> NotSupportedException: Modifications to tables where a primary key
>   column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not
>   supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'itemID'.
>   Table: 'DBEntities.Store.Item'.

The error generated when I click a button that contains this code

```
db.Items.Add(new Item
        {
            name = tbxItemName.Text,
            description = lblDescription.Text,
            date = DateTime.Now
         });
```

I believe the error might be because, from the SQL Side, I had something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Item 
(
    sno                     INT IDENTITY,
    itemID as CAST('ITM' + REPLICATE('0', 4-len(sno)) + CAST(sno as VARCHAR) as CHAR(7)) PERSISTED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name                    VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    description             VARCHAR(255),
    date                DATETIME            NOT NULL
);
```

Usually, I just insert value in SQL like

```
INSERT INTO Item (name, description, date) VALUES ('Car','Volvo','2017-05-20 12:12:12);
```

Item Class

```
public partial class Item
{
    public int sno { get; set; }
    public string itemID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Do you think the error is because of the SQL side?

Comment: would you mind adding the Item class to the question?

Comment: @Kokolo Hi, I just added the Item Class, Thank you!

Comment: Any fluent configuration? See, the problem is in EF mapping side, it's good that you showed the db table, but now we need to see the full EF mapping in order to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi, don't have any fluent configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Still something is missing - w/o any configuration / data annotations I'm getting different error ("itemId" is required). Is this code first? The error you are getting says the `itemId` is computed, where and how did you configure that?

Comment: I answered bellow, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi, thanks for the reply, This is Database-First and I did not configure itemID to be computed, when I do the tutorial of DatabaseFirst, it is auto generate. Thanks!

Comment: Then go to the edmx designer, select the `itemId` and make sure it's marked as identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string as key, add this data attribute in front of itemID:
This tells EF that you want a string as a key.

What's more important the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None tells the database that you will manually insert the Key value. (unlike integers, where the database auto-increments the ID)

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string itemID { get; set; }
```

If you want a clean model class (my preferred way) you can use the fluent API in your CONTEXT class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasKey(t => t.itemId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Let me know if this solves it.

EDIT3:
I deleted the unneeded info.

If you want to ignore sno, you should tell EF that:

```
[NotMapped]
public int sno;
```

My bad about HasDatabase.... method.
You should get the property first like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasKey(t => t.itemID)
                .Property(x =>x.itemID)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I used both solution and it is not working. I had error message when using the first one
    'EntityTypeConfiguration<Item> does not contain a definition for 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption' and no extension method 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption' accepting a first argument of type ..'

By the way, the PK is itemID. The reason I had 'sno' is that in the DB side, I used it as an Integer to increment to generate the PK like 'ITM0001', 'ITM0002' and so on.

I used the second solution and had the same error message like the initial one

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: take a look now.

Comment: fluent api for [not mapped]: modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().Ignore(t => t.sno);

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot but still received the initial error of  `NotSupportedException: Modifications to tables where a primary k..` :< Can I ask what would happen if I just changed 'StoreGeneratedPattern' to identity? It works, but Is that the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: If you are database first -> StoreGeneratedPattern is the way to go I suppose.

But, if you are in code-first, and you have an empty DB for now, I strongly suggest you drop and recreate the database every time the model changes. 
Because I started to believe that NotSupportedException is caused due to model changing.

you can do that in your context class:
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Item>());

Comment: I must note that, this is not the way to do it, this is just for development process.
In future if you need changes in the database, you'll have to use migrations

Comment: I set the Storedgeneratedpattern to Identity :D